# DisabledForUser Please make sure that the app id is set correctly when running npm run dev?

Tags: vue.js, npm, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm getting this message when I run `npm run dev`

*DisabledForUser Please make sure that the app id is set correctly.*

I have imported  javascript and css in the app.blade.php. Next, in the home.blade.php I'm using a div id="app" and I'm using inside the vue component called client.vue

App entry file

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div id="app">

<cliente></cliente>

</div>


@endsection
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
          //some css 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Docs</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Blog</a>
                    <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way , I'm hiding this message but I'm not sure It is the right way to solve this with mix.disableNotifications();
in webpack.mix.js , Let me know please.

Comment: I didn't want notifications for each build, so using: `mix.disableNotifications();` in `webpack.mix.js` was actually the solution for me

Answer (score 3):

Go to your windows settings **Windows settings → Notifications & actions** and enable notifications that try `npm run dev` again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have Notification enabled in your Windows setting for it to run. After you have it enabled run your code again and it work as intended.